# What's the correct way to write this IP valve?

Tags: java, regex, tomcat, tomcat8

I am trying to control access to my tomcat (version 8) sever by the requestor's ip address using a valve.  What I want is to allow all addresses that do not start with 10 and all addresses that start with 10.10.  Here is what I have.

`<valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve">
       allow="[^10]\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|10\.10\.\d+\.\d+" />`

It is not working, it allows access only to addresses starting with 10.10.

Regular expressions are not my best thing, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, what a weird idea from the Tomcat developers to only implement regexp-based IP filtering and not netmask-based.

Comment: Using regex is overkill imo.  I'd much rather have a netmask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow all addresses starting with 10.10. you can use the following regular expression:

```
10\.10\..*
```

`\.` corresponds to the "dot" character and `.*` corresponds to anything.

To forbid all addressed starting with `10.` you must write something more complex: `[^1].*` corresponds to anything which is not started with `1`. That's fine, if IP address does not start with `1` we will allow it. `1[^0].*` corresponds to any IP address which starts with `1` but second character is not `0`. `11xxx`, `15xxx`, etc. But we must allow addresses like `101.xxx`. So we will have to write `10[^.].*`. This expression will allow anything but `10.xxx` which is fine.

So the final regular expression will look like alternative between all expressions above:

```
10\.10\..*|[^1].*|1[^0].*|10[^.].*
```

or to slightly simplify:

```
(10\.10\.|[^1]|1[^0]|10[^.]).*
```

Now it's better to add `^` in the beginning and `$` in the end, just to be sure that this expression will check the entire IP address:

```
^(10\.10\.|[^1]|1[^0]|10[^.]).*$
```

I didn't check that input value is IP address at all, but I'm sure that tomcat won't pass anything but IP address for this check.

Answer (score 0):

[^10] won't exclude the strings starting with 10, it will match any character which is different from one or zero. So the first part of your pattern would accept the following IP addresses:
2.X.Y.Z, 3.X.Y.Z, ..., 9.X.Y.Z.

To achieve your goal, you could try something like this:

```
d\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|[02-9]d\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|[1-9]dd\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|10\.10\.\d+\.\d+
```

In this way, the first alternative will accept any IP's that start with a single digit. The second one, any IP's with start with two digits, excluding 10. The third one, any IP's which start with three digits (and thus cannot be 10 either).

One more remark, though: by using d+ to match the number, even invalid values might be accepted as IP components (which should be between 0-255), such as 257, 3848 etc. But that might be ok for your problem domain.